# Comparing combinations of enums with switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I need to compare different combinations of two enum values in the same switch and the only way I was doing it so far is by nesting switches like this:

```
enum enum1
{
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,
    H,I,J,K,L,M,N
};

enum enum2
{
    O,P,R,S,T,U,V,
    Z,X,Y
};

enum1 x;
enum2 y;

switch(x)
{
    case A:
        switch(y)
        {
            case O:
                // do stuff
                break;
        }
    case B:
        switch(y)
        {
            case O:
            // do stuff
            break;
        }
     // etc...
}
```

This approach makes my switches really long, and I'm trying to implement some different approach to reduce the amount of code...
for example something like this does not work:

```
int combination = C | P; // combine two enum values (enums from above code)

switch(combination)
{
    case (A | P):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case (B | O): // error: duplicate value
        break;
}
```

can you recommend some good approach on how to achieve the best results by not typing too much case this: case that: ?

Comment: Should this be tagged C instead of C++?  I don't see anything C++ specific.

Comment: This is C++ syntax, are you saying the above code does not compile with C++ compiler??

Comment: It's perfectly valid C++ syntax.  It just doesn't use any C++ language features (classes, templates, etc.).  Perhaps a C and C++ tag?

Comment: thanks, you can edit my tags if you wish, but I plain dislike C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the switch is that when calculating the bit-wise OR of the cases the same value appear more than one time (ex: A | P is the same than B | O), if is not assigned a value for the elements of the enum they take values from 0..n, you could assigning specific values to the elements of the enum, in the recommended case they are power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, ...) bit flags, this assure you that when apply bit-wise OR there will be no identical values (all elements of the enum have different bit of the int, this mean also, that could not be more than 32 enum elements in total, counting enum1 and enum2).

The first case propose assign values always beginning in 0x1 (in this case a shift is needed to one of the enums because if not the bit flags will collide and could be repeated values again). The macro could and should if C++11 is allowed be change by a constexpr.

The second case (recommended) assign the values to the enum elements already shifted and don't need macro or constexpr.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum enum1_1 { A = 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8 };
enum enum2_1 { O = 1, P = 2, R = 4, S = 8 };

enum enum1_2 { AA = 0x00000001, BB = 0x00000002, CC = 0x00000004, DD = 0x00000008 };
enum enum2_2 { OO = 0x00010000, PP = 0x00020000, RR = 0x00040000, SS = 0x00080000 };

#define COMB(en1, en2) (en1) | (en2 << 16)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Case 1
    enum1_1 x = A;
    enum2_1 y = O;
    int combination1 = COMB(x, y);
    switch (combination1) {
      case COMB(A, O): std::cout << "comb a-o" << std::endl; break;
      case COMB(A, P): std::cout << "comb a-p" << std::endl; break;
      case COMB(A, R): std::cout << "comb a-r" << std::endl; break;
      case COMB(A, S): std::cout << "comb a-s" << std::endl; break;
      case COMB(B, O): std::cout << "comb b-o" << std::endl; break;
      case COMB(B, P): std::cout << "comb b-p" << std::endl; break;
      case COMB(B, R): std::cout << "comb b-r" << std::endl; break;
      case COMB(B, S): std::cout << "comb b-s" << std::endl; break;
    }

    // Case 2
    enum1_2 xx = BB;
    enum2_2 yy = PP;
    int combination2 = xx | yy;
    switch (combination2) {
      case AA | OO: std::cout << "comb a-o" << std::endl; break;
      case AA | PP: std::cout << "comb a-p" << std::endl; break;
      case AA | RR: std::cout << "comb a-r" << std::endl; break;
      case AA | SS: std::cout << "comb a-s" << std::endl; break;
      case BB | OO: std::cout << "comb b-o" << std::endl; break;
      case BB | PP: std::cout << "comb b-p" << std::endl; break;
      case BB | RR: std::cout << "comb b-r" << std::endl; break;
      case BB | SS: std::cout << "comb b-s" << std::endl; break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your above approach with using the | symbol only works if you associate unique bit values to each of your code, because you are actually doing an OR operation on the integer bit values.  When you define each item, try associating a unique bit with each one.

For example:

```
enum enum1 {
   A = 0x00000001,
   B = 0x00000002,
   C = 0x00000004,
   D = 0x00000008,
   E = 0x00000010,
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise OR'ing the enums as written is going to cause duplicate values, since the `enum1` and `enum2` domains overlap.  If you ensure that the enumerated values in `enum1` and `enum2` don't share any of the same bits, you should be able to use the bitwise OR technique.

See @user2835484

Answer (score -1):

actually you can combine more than one case in one, as you point in the combination example, but I think the syntax is should be like this:

```
switch(combination)
{
    case A: case P:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case B: case O: // error: duplicate value
        break;
}
```